# Sequelize PostgresSQL - Column does not exist when it does

Tags: node.js, angularjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

I do not understand why my api is calling this column and not courseSection.courseId. from postman

[image]

I am building my project using AngularJs, PostgresSQL, NodeJs and Sequelize ORM.

This is my part of my **course.contorller.js**:

```js
const db = require("../models");
const Course = db.course;
    
//view course catalogue 
exports.retrieveAll = (req, res) => {
    Course.findAll({
          include: [{
            model: db.courseSection,
            as: "courseSection"
          }, {
            model: db.category,
            as: "category"
          }]
        })
        .then(data => {
          res.send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message
          });
        }); };
```

This is my **course.model.js**

```js
      module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
          const Course = sequelize.define(
            "course",
            {
              courseId: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
              },
              name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
                validate: {
                  notEmpty: true,
                },
              },
              description: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
              },
              creditPrice: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
              },
              isArchived: {
                type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
                defaultValue: false,
              },
              isDraft: {
                type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
              },
              level: {
                type: Sequelize.ENUM({
                  values: [
                    "PRIMARY 1",
                    "PRIMARY 2",
                    "PRIMARY 3",
                    "PRIMARY 4",
                    "PRIMARY 5",
                    "PRIMARY 6",
                  ],
                }),
              },
              createdAt: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
              },
              updatedAt: {
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
              },
            },
            {
              classMethods: {
                associate: function (models) {
                  Course.hasMany(models.CourseSection, {
                    foreignKey: "courseId",
                    onDelete: "CASCADE",
                  });
                  Course.hasMany(models.Material, {
                    foreignKey: "courseId",
                    onDelete: "CASCADE",
                  });
                  Course.hasMany(models.Review, {
                    foreignKey: "courseId",
                    onDelete: "CASCADE",
                  });
                  Course.hasMany(models.Enrolment, {
                    foreignKey: "courseId",
                    onDelete: "CASCADE",
                  });
                  Course.belongsTo(models.Category, {
                    foreignKey: "categoryId",
                    onDelete: "CASCADE",
                  });
                  Course.belongsTo(models.User, {
                    foreignKey: "userId",
                    onDelete: "CASCADE",
                  });
                },
              },
            }
          );
        
          return Course;
        };
```

**My courseSection.js**

```js
    module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
      const CourseSection = sequelize.define(
        "courseSection",
        {
          sectionId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
          name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notEmpty: true,
            },
          },
          isArchived: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false,
          },
          createdAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
          updatedAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
        },
        {
          classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
              CourseSection.belongsTo(models.Course, {
                foreignKey: "courseId",
                onDelete: "CASCADE",
              });
            },
          },
        }
      );
    
      return CourseSection;
    };
```

My **migration for course.js**

```js
    "use strict";
    
    //npx sequelize migration:generate --name course
    module.exports = {
      up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable("course", {
          courseId: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
          categoryId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            references: {
              model: "category",
              key: "categoryId",
            },
          },
          userId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            references: {
              model: "user",
              key: "userId",
            },
          },
          name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notEmpty: true,
            },
          },
          description: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
          },
          creditPrice: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          },
          isArchived: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false,
          },
          isDraft: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
          },
          level: {
            type: Sequelize.ENUM({
              values: [
                "PRIMARY 1",
                "PRIMARY 2",
                "PRIMARY 3",
                "PRIMARY 4",
                "PRIMARY 5",
                "PRIMARY 6",
              ],
            }),
          },
          createdAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
          updatedAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
        });
      },
    
      down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable("course");
      },
    };
```

My **migration for courseSection**

```js
    "use strict";
    
    module.exports = {
      up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.createTable("courseSection", {
          sectionId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
          },
          name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              notEmpty: true,
            },
          },
          courseId: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            onDelete: "CASCADE",
            references: {
              model: "course",
              key: "courseId",
            },
          },
          isArchived: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false,
          },
          createdAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
          updatedAt: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
          },
        });
      },
    
      down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        return queryInterface.dropTable("courseSection");
      },
    };
```

My **index.js** in /model

[image]

my postgres table:

[image]

When I do localhost:3000/courses/course, my vscode shows the following error:

> Executing (default): SELECT "course"."courseId", "course"."name", "course"."description", "course"."creditPrice", "course"."isArchived", "course"."isDraft", "course"."level", "course"."createdAt", "course"."updatedAt", "course"."categoryCategoryId", "course"."categoryId", "course"."userId", "course"."userUserId", "courseSection"."sectionId" AS "courseSection.sectionId", "courseSection"."name" AS "courseSection.name", "courseSection"."isArchived" AS "courseSection.isArchived", "courseSection"."createdAt" AS "courseSection.createdAt", "courseSection"."updatedAt" AS "courseSection.updatedAt", "courseSection"."courseCourseId" AS "courseSection.courseCourseId", "courseSection"."courseId" AS "courseSection.courseId", "category"."categoryId" AS "category.categoryId", "category"."isArchived" AS "category.isArchived", "category"."name" AS "category.name", "category"."createdAt" AS "category.createdAt", "category"."updatedAt" AS "category.updatedAt" FROM "course" AS "course" LEFT OUTER JOIN "courseSection" AS "courseSection" ON "course"."courseId" = "courseSection"."courseCourseId" LEFT OUTER JOIN "category" AS "category" ON "course"."categoryId" = "category"."categoryId";

I have been on this problem for the past 2 days and I honestly do not know where I went wrong. I hope anyone can help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You defined associations between `courseSection` and `course` twice:

- in `associate` methods of a model classes (correct ones)
- in `index.js` without indicating `foreignKey` option

I suppose you just need to remove associations in `index.js` and just call `associate` methods of models in `index.js`.

Something like

```js
db.category.associate(db.models);
// and so on
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the quick reply. Do you mean removing the entire section from my index.js?

I did that but now i have an error saying "courseSection is not associated to course!" despite there being an association in the models

Comment: Yes, the whole piece of code with associations. And did you add `associate` calls for all models that have associations?

Comment: I am sorry, I might be confused or misunderstanding. All of my models that have associations with other models are associated correctly. What is this associate call and where do I put it? Do I put it these associate calls, db.category.associate(db.models), at?

Comment: I apologise for being overbearing!

Comment: You should call `associate(db.models)` for all your models in `index.js`